# Method Signature Refactoring

Tags: java, refactoring

I have multiple databases of users that I have to search on. The user can have multiple instances and the app checks if the user is a duplicate across the different databases.

So each user is associated with a client, and the fields are populated differently based on what client it is. (I know it's not right, but this is inherited application) My thought would be to refactor it by adding the client as a parameter into the getUserData method. However i'm realizing this is a change preventer smell. There are many wrapper methods that will pass in default values. i also have to traverse the call hiearchy far back enough that I would have access to the client object to pass in. This may be for or five method calls, so I would have to change those as well. At this point, the way the app was developed(by other developers) is very rigid when it comes to this, and I am looking to improve it.

The getUserData method:

```
public User getUserData(String userId, boolean fullUserRecord, Date userStartDate){
    //retrive userdata from db
    //attach client specific data for user

}
```

Example of a wrapper method:

```
public User getUserData(String userId,  Date userStartDate){
    getUserData(userId, false, userStartDate)

}
```

My question would be, how do I best handle this. Currently i am going down the rabbit hole of changing the method signature, but if this needs to change again, I would have to do the same thing, which won't be fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrapper methods serve no purpose whatsoever.
Introduce a parameter object and inline the wrapper methods where possible.

"Introduce parameter object" refactoring:

- http://refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html
- https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/introduce-parameter-object

Comment: So since I have many chained calls linked to the method signature I want to change, I should use preserve whole object and start the refactoring at the beginning of the call chain?

Comment: I would do the reverse: start at the bottom where you can see all the parameters, then inline gradually. Moreover if many parameters are optional, you may create specialized constructors, or method factories for the parameter object. You may even go one step further and create a fluent builder if that helps readability.

Comment: i ended up creating the parameter object with specialized constructors. Now the code is a lot more manageable. I may look into create a builder for the object to make it even more readable. Thanks!

Comment: I was able to create the builder to create the object and ridded my code of the constructors needed to create the param objects. Much more elegant now!

Comment: Glad that helped you :)